# Display of dimensions in (multiple) correspondence analysis

Tags: correspondence-analysis

I am getting into correspondence analysis and was wondering what the correct way is to display more than two dimensions in a biplot. I found examples with biplots showing dimensions plotted in order (Dim1+Dim2, Dim3+Dim4), but also higher dimensions being compared to the first or second dimension. Is there a reason for going with one or the other method? And what is the reasoning?